Contextually, does Peter in 1 Peter 5:10 addresses on the perseverance or spiritual maturity and building the Christian life through suffering?
Text: 1 Peter 5:10 (NET)

And, after you have suffered for a little while, the God of all grace
who called you to his eternal glory in Christ will himself restore,
confirm, strengthen, and establish you.


Definitely the latter.

Peter addresses both perseverance and suffering which can lead to spiritual maturity.
Peter teaches believers how to be mature:

Elders are to shepherd the flock willingly and eagerly, guiding
others towards spiritual growth (1 Peter 5:1-4).
Be humble and submit to God’s mighty hand (1 Peter 5:5-6).
Be sober-minded, watchful, and resist the devil, standing firm in
faith (1 Peter 5:8-9).
Share in the same kinds of suffering experienced by believers around the world. (1 Peter 5:9).
Persevere through temporary suffering, knowing it leads to eternal
glory (1 Peter 5:1, 4, 10).

After the period of suffering, God Himself will “restore, confirm, strengthen, and establish” the believers. Believers have the opportunity to grow and be fortified in their faith through their trials.

This is what we have to look forward to in eternity. God will restore
us and perfect us; we will not be lacking anything. He will make us
strong, hold us firm, and be steadfast. In this life we might struggle
and face suffering. We can feel our bodies being worn out. [1]

Christians are promised an end to suffering.
Romans 5:3-5 says,

Not only that, but we rejoice in our sufferings, knowing that suffering produces endurance, and endurance produces character, and character produces hope, and hope does not put us to shame, because
God's love has been poured into our hearts through the Holy Spirit who
has been given to us.

Elsewhere in 1 Peter 1:6-7 it is written,

In this you rejoice, though now for a little while, if necessary, you have been grieved by various trials, so that the tested genuineness of your faith—more precious than gold that perishes though it is tested
by fire—may be found to result in praise and glory and honor at the
revelation of Jesus Christ.

James 1:2-4 says,

Count it all joy, my brothers, when you meet trials of various kinds, for you know that the testing of your faith produces steadfastness. And let steadfastness have its full effect, that you may be perfect and complete, lacking in nothing.

